# Coding around issues with a functional ListView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom configuration page in my app which just so happens to contain a `ListView` which you can select/deselect, edit, add to and remove items from. Since the amount of configuration is so large I've had to put it all in a `ScrollView`

My problem is of course that you cannot have scroll functionality within a view which already has it's own scroll functionality. This means I can't have a scrolling `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`.

What I've been trying to do is find the best way of limiting the damage this does. I've seen suggestions that say "You could just create a LinearLayout which grows as you add more children". That would work find by the added effort required to plug in the selectable nature, the reordering & sorting of the list as well as the editing would be a maintanance nightmare.

I've spent the day trying to find a way of measuring the height of each ListView item. Once I can find the size of each item (not just the content but any padding and space between items) on each device I know I can simply change the height of the `ListView` per item added.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to reliably pull back the height of a listviews child.

(The old chestnut of using a GlobalLayoutListener doesn't help me pull back the padding between items)

```
final TextView listLabel = (TextView) toReturn.findViewById(R.id.listLabel);
final ViewTreeObserver vto = listLabel.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        listLabel.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        mListItemHeight = listLabel.getHeight();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Expanding ListView's are you're friend - This `LinearLayout` expands based on it's content. It allows Dynamic `ListView`'s inside of `ScrollView`.

```
public class LinearListView extends LinearLayout {

    private BaseAdapter mAdapter;
    private Observer mObserver;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClickListener;

    public LinearListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public LinearListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public LinearListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mObserver = new Observer();
    }

    public void setAdapter(BaseAdapter adapter) {
        if (this.mAdapter != null)
            this.mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mObserver);

        this.mAdapter = adapter;
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(mObserver);
        mObserver.onChanged();
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public void setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemLongClickListener = listener;
    }

    private int mListSelector = R.drawable.selector_list;
    public void setListSelector(int resid) {
        mListSelector = resid;
    }

    private class Observer extends DataSetObserver {
        public Observer(){}

        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            List<View> oldViews = new ArrayList<View>(getChildCount());

            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++)
                oldViews.add(getChildAt(i));

            Iterator<View> iter = oldViews.iterator();

            removeAllViews();

            for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                final int index = i;
                View convertView = iter.hasNext() ? iter.next() : null;
                View toAdd = mAdapter.getView(i, convertView, LinearListView.this);
                toAdd.setBackgroundResource(mListSelector);
                toAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(null, v, index, index);
                        }
                    }
                });
                toAdd.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        if(mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                            mOnItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClick(null, v, index, index);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }                   
                });
                LinearListView.this.addView(toAdd, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
            super.onChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            removeAllViews();
            super.onInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're trying to display too many details on your page? You could split the activity in a summary with buttons that lead to multiple one-screen-long activities.

In my experience, users usually prefer an uncluttered and clear view, even if that means having to click once or twice to get to the part they want.

Comment: In this case that's not an issue. The screen isn't cluttered, it's surprising how little you can fit on a phone screen. This is all a case of edge scenarios meeting.

Comment: It is indeed surprising. Forces you to adopt a whole new set of good design practices. And it can be frustrating when, modification after modification, by just adding a small list here, another sentence here, a little icon there, suddenly you're out of room :)